# POST submit fails and redirects

Tags: forms, url, session, post, get

This is something weird. I'm letting users submit a URL using a POST form. This form and everything that has anything to do with it is in a subfolder in my main `public_html`. The resulting PHP, which lies on the same page as the form, does this:

```
if (filter_var($_POST['input-addr'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    $_SESSION['scy-prox-url'] = $_POST['input-addr'];
} else {
    $_SESSION['scy-prox-url'] = 'false';
}
```

Below that, it gets the contents of the requested URL file and does a huge amount of editing to the HTML.

If I enter something simple, like http://smashingmagazine.com/, it seems to fail and redirect me to a 404 not found page.

I created a GET client that does the same thing as above but using `$_GET` which works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it works for me here: http://codepad.org/zyXTCJDZ

I suspect it may be something in the code below what you've pasted.

Comment: I think it may be a problem with subdomains. I have a subdomain "blog.mywebsite.com" which points to "mywebsite.com/blog" and anything but this subdomain works fine.